# Making a sub directory with a folder structure from part of a path

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

If I have a path, like so:

> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\abc.exe

And I want to make a folder under a drive/path such as

> Z:\Stuff\

How can I make a sub directory and select whether I want everything from windows onwards, system32 onwards, or inetsrv onwards? BTW I know `DirectoryInfo` has a method called `CreateSubDirectory()`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path).  It is a static method unlike the DirectoryInfo one where you need an instance of a directory to call it.

After that you could use Xcopy or Robocopy to copy all the files and subdirectories.

Comment: So would that create me a path like Z:\Stuff\Windows\... so on up to inetsrv?

Comment: @dotnetdev: It will create all parts of the path that does not exist. Except, of course, from the drive letter ;)

Comment: Xcopy c:\windows z:\Stuff /s  would.  Check the options in Xcopy to specify exactly what you want.  You can call Xcopy from C# by launching a new Process.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy everything from one directory to another you can use something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace so_cp__r
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter path from where you want to copy:");
            List<DirectoryInfo> fromDirs = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
            DirectoryInfo dir = new FileInfo(Console.ReadLine()).Directory;
            while (dir != null)
            {
                fromDirs.Add(dir);
                dir = dir.Parent;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < fromDirs.Count; i++)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, fromDirs[i].FullName);
            Console.WriteLine("From which of these dirs do you want to start?");
            DirectoryInfo fromDir = fromDirs[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())];
            Console.WriteLine("Where do you want to copy?");
            DirectoryInfo toDir = new DirectoryInfo(Console.ReadLine());
            recursive_copy(fromDir, toDir);
        }

        static void recursive_copy(DirectoryInfo fromDir, DirectoryInfo toDir)
        {
            DirectoryInfo child = toDir.CreateSubdirectory(fromDir.Name);
            foreach (FileInfo file in fromDir.GetFiles())
                file.CopyTo(child.FullName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + file.Name);
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in fromDir.GetDirectories())
                recursive_copy(dir, child);
        }
    }
}
```